# Given two lists, words & definitions . We Need to create a dictionary called cooldictionary where we use words for keys and definitions for values

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is the given sample lists

```
words = ["PoGo","Spange","Lie-Fi"]

definitions = ["Slang for Pokemon Go","To collect spare change, either from couches, passerbys on the street or any numerous other ways and means","When your phone or tablet indicates that you are connected to a wireless network, however you are still unable to load webpages or use any internet services with your device"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code which is implemented.

```
words = ["PoGo","Spange","Lie-Fi"]

definitions = ["Slang for Pokemon Go","To collect spare change, either from couches, passerbys on the street or any numerous other ways and means","When your phone or tablet indicates that you are connected to a wireless network, however you are still unable to load webpages or use any internet services with your device"] 

cooldictionary = {}
for word in words:
    for definition in definitions:
        cooldictionary[word] = definition
        definitions.remove(definition)
        break
    
print(cooldictionary)
```

Explanation:

In the above code we have created a *dictionary* named `cooldictionary`  which searches for each elements in a words dictionary and definitions dictionary and matches them in the form of key and value pair one by one for each index and removing them with every iteration untill the elements end and then it breaks the loop and print it finally.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cooldictionary = {a : b for (a,b) in zip(words, definitions)}
```

By thanks @Danimesejo you can try this:

```
cooldictionary = dict(zip(words, definitions))
```

Comment: `dict(zip(words, definitions))` is an alternative

Comment: @DaniMesejo, thanks a lot, you are so nice ;)

Comment: Your solution to the problem given is wrong @user1740577 since you have not created a variable named `cooldictionary`

Comment: There you go @user1740577 sir :) with an upvote